# Variable in URL

Tags: php, wordpress, arguments

I'm making a website with wordpress for my company and i have a question for you

I have an url like this

http://mysuperwebsite/?_sft_category=cx+ms+lol

And i would like to grab the argument of this, so i tried

```
$motsclefs = $_GET['_sft_category'] ;
```

and a basic echo

```
echo'<div>'.$motsclefs.'</div>';
```

This is cool but now this return me something like this in a single div

cx ms lol

My desire is to cut those words, to have as much div as my words

To be more specific i would like to have something like this

```
<div class="1">cx</div>
<div class="2">ms</div>
<div class="3">lol</div>
```

So, i understood that i have to consider those "+" in the url to separate my words ?

Thanks ;)

Comment: [explode](http://php.net/explode) and [foreach](http://php.net/foreach)? P.s. `+` in the URL is converted automatically to a space, so you'd explode on a space, not `+`.

Comment: So something like this ? print_r(explode(' ', $motsclefs, 100)); and a foreach loop to print all those ressources ? I'm gonna try

Comment: Not sure where you got the idea to use `print_r` but that won't work, it will print the entire array.

Comment: the print_r was just to see the array indeed, i want to see if it work that way before to go further ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string by a space, if $motsclefs is a string with spaces separating the arguments, which is how it looks from your question:

`$arguments = explode(" ", $motsclefs);`

Then iterate through them:

```
foreach ($arguments as $argument) {
    echo "<div>$argument</div>";
}
```

For different classes;

```
$i = 1;

foreach ($arguments as $argument) {
    echo "<div class='class$i'>$argument</div>";
    $i++;
}
```

`$i` increases for each loop round which will give you a new number with every iteration.

Comment: Yeah ! you're the best guys ! it works fine. But if i want a special class for each elements ?

Comment: Amazing, swift and accurate, you are really amazing guys ! :=) thanks a lot

Comment: another question for you guys ^^ In fact i would like to create "keywords" for this page, ii'm supposed to provide a clickable keyword that remove the query on the url onclick on it. How can I remove the query in the URL when i click on it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
$tempArr=explode(' ',$motsclefs);

for($i=0;$i < count($tempArr);$i++)
{

  echo '<div>'.$tempArr[$i].'</div>';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Jon Stirling use explode and foreach.

```
<?php

$motsclefs = 'cx ms lol';

$divs = '';
foreach(explode(' ', $motsclefs) as $key => $element) {
    $divs .= sprintf ('<div class="%s">%s</div>' . PHP_EOL, $key + 1, $element);
}
```